# Problems with protobuf when generating haxe source file

Tags: protocol-buffers, haxe

I want to generate protobuf source file with haxe,but the last step "haxelib run protohx generate protohx.json" come across the problem says

plugin: program not found or is not executable
--haxe_out: protoc-gen-haxe: Plugin failed with status code 1.

Anyone can fix it out?Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try another protobuf implementation: https://github.com/Atry/protoc-gen-haxe, which does not need you to generate Haxe source files any more.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and got around it by running the task manually to generate the proto class files.

I copied the plugin to my local path, then made the proto shell script executable:

For example:

```
chmod +x proto
protoc --plugin=protoc-gen-haxe=plugin --haxe_out=./src-gen --proto_path=. proto/your.proto
```